# funnel analysis with pandas (large data set)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to do some rudimentary funnel analysis with a pandas dataframe. Meaning, I have a dataframe containing user `sessions` that are made up of a series of `events`. I would like to be able to group by `session`, identify which `sessions` contain a given `event ordering` (eventA followed by eventB), and then group by `date` and get a count of these over time.

for example, given my dataframe:

```
sessions = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd']
events = ['dog', 'cat', 'tree', 'tree', 'dog', 'frog', 'cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'tree', 'cat', 'dog']
d1 = datetime(2014,8,1)
d2 = datetime(2014,8,2)
d3 = datetime(2014,8,3)
dates = [d1, d1, d1, d1, d1, d1, d1, d2, d2, d1, d1, d1]
dic = {'sessions':sessions, 'events':events, 'dates':dates}
df_tot = pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

producing:

```
    sessionDate  events  sessions
0   2014-08-01   dog     a
1   2014-08-01   cat     a
2   2014-08-01   tree    a
3   2014-08-01   tree    b
4   2014-08-01   dog     b
5   2014-08-01   frog    b
6   2014-08-01   cat     b
7   2014-08-02   dog     c
8   2014-08-02   cat     c
9   2014-08-01   tree    d
10  2014-08-01   cat     d
11  2014-08-01   dog     d
```

I would like to get the following for event ordering `dog` then `cat`:

```
             reachedFirstEvent   reachedSecondEvent  total
2014-08-01   1                   2                   3
2014-08-02   0                   1                   1
```

My second problem is, I have 3 million rows in my actual dataframe. So I built a hacked together solution. It works but is pretty slow. Any thoughts on how to do this or speed up my code?

```
def find_funnels_ex(dlist,event_list):

        m = -1
        for i in range(0,len(event_list)):

            j = np.where(dlist == event_list[i])[0] #get all indices where cat
            j = j[j>=m] #select only indices greater than min dog index
            if j.size == 0:
                return i
            else:
                m = np.min(j)

        return i+1

sessions = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd']
events = ['dog', 'cat', 'tree', 'tree', 'dog', 'frog', 'cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'tree', 'cat', 'dog']
d1 = datetime(2014,8,1)
d2 = datetime(2014,8,2)
d3 = datetime(2014,8,3)
dates = [d1, d1, d1, d1, d1, d1, d1, d2, d2, d1, d1, d1]
dic = {'sessions':sessions, 'events':events, 'dates':dates}
df_tot = pd.DataFrame(dic)


#get only groups that have at least first event
gb_tot = df_tot.groupby('sessions')
df_filt = gb_tot.filter(lambda x: 'dog' in x['events'].values) #changes to dataframe

#get funnel position for each session
#returns a 1 if first event is reached, returns a 2 if second event is reached, etc
gb_filt = df_filt.groupby('sessions')
gb_funn = gb_filt.aggregate(lambda x: find_funnels_ex(
                                x['events'].values, 
                                ['dog','cat']
                                )
                   ) 

#join this to funnel to get date events funnel was started
gb_filt = gb_filt.aggregate({'dates':np.min}) 
gb_filt['funnel'] = gb_funn['events']
df_funn = gb_filt.reset_index() #change back to dataframe

#pivot to get columns of funnel position indicators
df_piv = pd.pivot_table(df_funn,'funnel', cols='funnel', rows=['sessions','dates'], aggfunc=np.sum) #pivot
df_piv = df_piv.reset_index() #reset

#group by date and sum
df_piv = df_piv.set_index('dates') #set index
gb_piv = df_piv.groupby(lambda x: x) #groupby date
gb_final = gb_piv.aggregate({1:np.sum,2:np.sum})

#get totals
gb_tot = df_tot.groupby('sessions')
gb_tot = gb_tot.aggregate({'dates':np.min})
gb_tot = gb_tot.set_index('dates') #set index
gb_tot = gb_tot.groupby(lambda x: x).size() #groupby date
gb_final['total'] = gb_tot


gb_final[2] = gb_final.apply(lambda x: x[2]/2.0,axis=1)
```

Comment: Can you add a bit of detail in your example as to why `reachedFirstEvent` is `0` for `2014-08-02`?  If the criteria to reach first even is `dog` in session then doesn't session `c` qualify?

Comment: Right, so that comes from my find_funnels_ex() function. If and only if the second part of the funnel is reached, it returns 2. Else, if only the first part is reached it returns 1. So, you are correct, the actual count of firstEventReached should be columns 1 + 2

Comment: Sounds good, working on a writeup of something that might help.  To understand better again, your goal is to do two things: 1) identify sessions that reach first and/or second event and 2) for each date sum the number of sessions that qualify with those booleans?  Also, the date array you have doesn't produce the df you list.  it needs to read `[d1,d1,d1,d1,d1,d1,d1,d2,d2,d1,d1,d1]`

Comment: awesome thanks! I came up with a second solution below but its still pretty laggy. And Yes, as you said above, that is exactly what I want

Comment: Does `dog` have to be the first event in the session for it to qualify as `reachedFirst` or if dog is anywhere in the session it has `reachedFirst`?

Comment: anywhere in the session :) I just care about the ordering, not event index in session.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another version I thought up. Similarly slow with a lot of data though :(

This function determines whether a session includes the current funnel:

```
def find_funnels(dlist,event_list):

    m = -1
    for i in range(0,len(event_list)):

        j = np.where(dlist == event_list[i])[0]
        j = j[j>=m]
        if j.size == 0:
            return False
        else:
            m = np.min(j)

    return True
```

This function applies the current funnel to the df:

```
def funnelz(df, eventList, groups, dates, events):

    dfz = pd.DataFrame()
    count = 1
    eventList2 = [eventList[0]]

    while eventList:

        if not dfz.empty:
            gb = df.groupby(groups)
            df = gb.filter(lambda x: find_funnels(x[events].values, eventList2))

        gb = df.groupby(groups)
        gb = gb.aggregate({dates:np.min})
        gb = gb.set_index(dates)
        gb = gb.groupby(lambda x: x).size()

        if not dfz.empty:
            dfz['event'+str(count)+'Reached'] = gb
            count += 1
            eventList = eventList[1:]
            if eventList:
                eventList2.append(eventList[0])

        else:
            dfz['total'] = gb

    return dfz
```

seems to work but slow:

```
funnelz(df_funn, eventList=['dog', 'cat'], groups = 'sessions', dates = 'dates', events = 'events')
```